# Eclipse complains android:scrollbars and android:fadingEdge do not allow Strings - includes code

Tags: xml, android, eclipse

Having a problem in Eclipse with regards to an XML file. Eclipse complains that android:scrollbars and android:fadingEdge do not allow Strings.  I checked the Android developer site and they do in fact accept strings in the xml file. A related question posed had the problem where there was a missing :android after xmlns. As you can see from the code the line beginning with xmlns is correct I believe. Here is the complete file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <com.example.todolist.TodoListItemView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:scrollbars="verticle"
  android:textColor="@color/notepad_text"
  android:fadingEdge="verticle"
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you've misspelled "vertical"! Once you correct that, it should recognise it properly.